# read() not working properly in c

Tags: c, io

I am trying to get the value of the first character in a file by using the read function from unistd and I am having troubles with a strange behavior :

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char uselessTable[600];
    int fdInput;
    int firstChar;

    if ((fdInput = open("file.txt", O_RDONLY)) == -1) {
        perror("file");
        _exit(1);
    }

    read(fdInput, &firstChar, 1);
    printf("Taille du nom de fichier : %d\n", firstChar); // prints 32609

    if (close(fdInput) == -1) {
        perror("close");
        _exit(2);
    }
}
```

The file contains the string abc so it should print the number 97 but it doesn't, unless I remove the table uselessTable, even though it is not being used in this program.

Changing the size of the table to 500, removing it, creating it after firstChar or changing int firstChar to char firstChar seems to fix the problem but I don't understand why.

Comment: It's because read() is only overwriting the first byte of the firstChar int, leading to undefined behaviour. Make firstChar a char, and cast it to an int when you use printf() on it.

Comment: You read one byte into an `int` (which takes more than one byte), leaving the other bytes uninitialized.

Answer (score 1):

Let's go through this step-by-step. First, you create a local variable `firstChar`, which is an `int` rather than a `char`. Local variables that aren't initialised (and that aren't `static`) can be set to any arbitrary value.

We'll say, for the sake of simplicity, that the `int` data type is actually four bytes long.

The next step is that you read a *single* `char` variable into the address of that four-byte `int`. So what you end up with is the memory:

```
           +-----+-----+-----+-----+
firstChar: | 'a' |  ?  |  ?  |  ?  |
           +-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

with the first byte of that `int` set to 97 (assuming ASCII) and the other bytes still set to some arbitrary value.

Since the integer is formed by all *four* bytes, that's why you're getting something like `32609`.

The obvious solution is to use a `char` variable which will just use the *one* byte. That way, when you overwrite that byte, it will fully represent what you read in:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char firstChar = 0xff; // force it so you *know* it changes.
    int fdInput = open("file.txt", O_RDONLY);
    if (fdInput == -1) {
        perror("file");
        _exit(1);
    }

    read(fdInput, &firstChar, 1);
    printf("Taille du nom de fichier : %d\n", firstChar); // prints 97

    close(fdInput);
}
```